# PHP need set date based on time

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I have an simple question about how to set date based on time range. This is my code so far:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$time = date("G:i");
if ($time >= 8:00)
{
    echo date("j-F-Y");
}
else
{
    echo date("j-F-Y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Example today is 29-Apr-2013.
Now I want before time 8:00 the date will still 28-Apr-2013. After that, date will continue to 29-Apr-2013.

The code is successfully complete the rule, if time before 8:00. But if I changed my computer time to be 11:00 or etc, it will set yesterday back.

Comment: Your code compares strings, not the time. So `'11:00' < '8:00'` because `1<8`

Comment: That code as is shouldn't even run due to syntax errors.

Comment: `if (date('G') >= 8) { ... }` would do it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = date("G:i");
if ($time >= 8:00)
```

This comparison is not good. Try numerically like

```
$time = intval(date("Gi"));
if ($time >= 800)
```